# Geometric Structures of a fixed area.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Lets $M_A$ be the space of metrics of area $A$ on a two dimensional surface $S$, and let $D_0$ be the group of area-preserving diffeomorphisms whose right action on $M_A$ is given by pullback. The author says that $\frac{M_A}{D_0}$ is the space of geometric structures of area $A$ in a given conformal class.

What exactly does the last sentence mean? What is a geometric structure and what does it mean for one to be in a conformal class of another? Why is this quotient non-trivial? Is it not true that given two metrics of the same area that there is always a diffeomorphism that pulls back one metric to the other?

Comment: What is the author's definition of an area-preserving diffeomorphism? I'm guessing it's preserving the area form locally, not just preserving the total area. Thus a coset of $D_0$ is just the set of metrics with a given area form $dA$ , with exactly one representative $(dA/d\mu_g) g$ from each conformal class $[g]$.